# How to run useEffect on component mount as well as state changes

Tags: javascript, react-hooks

I have a useEffect function which runs only when the *page* state changes, but I want to run this function on both component mount as well as state change.

To accomplish this I used two variables in dependency array

> , [page, []]

Using this expression in dependency array shows a warning in the console and the useEffect method runs infinitely, I don't know how to fix this.

My useEffect funtion is

```js
// fetch data from the server when page changes
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(fetchURL, { headers: { Authorization: AuthStr } })
      .then((response) => {
        // If request is good...
        if (response) {
          setData(response.data);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        toast.error('Something went wrong, please refresh');
        console.log(error);
      });
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [page]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Please suggest a possible solution to this problem.

Comment: The current version already runs on mount?

Comment: Your `useEffect` does run on the component mount with just the `[page]` dependency. What is happening to make you think it does not?

Comment: You don't need to put any other arguments in the dep array, every useEffect already runs on mount, adding arguments in the dep array just means it *also* runs when those deps change

Comment: useEffect always gets called on component did mount. adding [page] dependency will also call useEffect when page state changes. adding just [] will keep it from always calling itself.

Comment: Yes current version runs on mount, but I have a update section in the component, which update data and after every update I want to make this useEffect run and fetch the latest data. Right now after I update data I have to refresh the page to see changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will run after mount as well as if there is any change in value of "page" which you have passed in the dependency array. Perform some change in "page" and you will see that it will re-render. If there is some other entity that you are using to deduce that there is change in state you should include that also in dependency array.